# Variation of PDF

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, density-function

Suppose I have the PDF
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{12x^2}{7}
$$
with $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

What would be the PDF of $Y = X^2$?

Would it be
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{12x^{1/2}}{49},\quad 0 \leq y \leq 1 ?
$$

Comment: Can you show the details of how you got that result?

Comment: It's just a guess, I'm not really sure what i'm doing

Comment: I think my answer is enough to address your doubt. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Note that yours is not a valid density, i.e. $f_X(x)$ doesn't integrate to 1. Indeed

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{12x^2}{7}\,dx = \frac{8}{7}.
$$

The correct density should thus be $f_X(x)= \frac{3x^2}{2}.$ For $Y = X^2$ we have

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^2\leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}).\tag{*}
\end{align*}

To obtain $f_Y$ compute the above integral in (*) and differentiate w.r.t $y$.